# IntelliJ cannot import maven projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA community edition and got the latest version around two months ago. I have this huge problem that whenever I try to import or make a maven project I get the unhelpful message "Unable to import maven project: See logs for details" from the editor.

What really stumps me and those I have asked for help so far is that this issue seems completely isolated to me and everyone else around me importing the same projects can do so with ease. The logs haven't been helpful to me at all either and when I tried following some other solutions for this on Stack Overflow nothing happened.

I have also tried re-installing IntelliJ it fixed it but only for that particular time i used IntelliJ.

I have the logs but the dump in it is far too long to put into a question.

So, do any of you have any idea what I should do?

Putting partial dump here in any case just to try. Just the first part.

```
2017-09-26 12:09:12,894 [  47064]   WARN - tectAndAdjustIndentOptionsTask - Indent detection is too long for: Main.java 
2017-09-26 12:09:12,894 [  47064]   WARN - tectAndAdjustIndentOptionsTask - Indent detection is too long for: Vinir.json 
2017-09-26 12:09:12,895 [  47065]   WARN - tectAndAdjustIndentOptionsTask - Indent detection is too long for: Friends.java 
2017-09-26 12:09:12,895 [  47065]   WARN - tectAndAdjustIndentOptionsTask - Indent detection is too long for: Books.java 
2017-09-26 12:09:12,895 [  47065]   WARN - tectAndAdjustIndentOptionsTask - Indent detection is too long for: Borrowers.java 
2017-09-26 12:09:12,895 [  47065]   WARN - tectAndAdjustIndentOptionsTask - Indent detection is too long for: Bækur.json 
2017-09-26 12:09:17,655 [  51825]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 18 project components initialized in 52 ms 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,767 [2842937]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,768 [2842938]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,768 [2842938]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,788 [2842958]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,789 [2842959]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,801 [2842971]   INFO - Types.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl - FileTypeManager: 0 auto-detected files
Elapsed time on auto-detect: 0 ms 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,808 [2842978]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,811 [2842981]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,819 [2842989]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,822 [2842992]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-09-26 12:55:48,824 [2842994]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,909 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,919 [     10]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.25 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,919 [     10]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 1.25 (IDE-managed HiDPI) 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,953 [     44]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-172.4155.36, 11 Sep 2017 19:07) 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,953 [     44]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,953 [     44]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b11 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,953 [     44]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.152-b11 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,975 [     66]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=D:\download\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:D:\download\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.jre.check=true -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2017.2 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\Grimur\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\Grimur\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,975 [     66]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: D:\download\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\jre64\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-09-27 12:13:07,975 [     66]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1252 
2017-09-27 12:13:08,047 [    138]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 71 ms 
2017-09-27 12:13:08,070 [    161]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-09-27 12:13:08,071 [    162]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2017-09-27 12:13:10,577 [   2668]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2017-09-27 12:13:11,447 [   3538]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 32 plugins initialized in 1383 ms 
2017-09-27 12:13:11,452 [   3543]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.2.3), Ant Support (1.0), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (172.4155.36), Eclipse Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (172.4155.36), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (172.4155.36), Gradle (172.4155.36), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (172.4155.36), IDEA CORE (172.4155.36), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (172.4155.36), JavaFX (1.0), Kotlin (1.1.4-release-IJ2017.2-3), Maven Integration (172.4155.36), Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support (172.4155.36), Settings Repository (172.4155.36), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), UI Designer (172.4155.36), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (172.4155.36), hg4idea (10.0) 
2017-09-27 12:13:18,972 [  11063]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=705 
2017-09-27 12:13:19,124 [  11215]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: D:\download\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2017-09-27 12:13:19,172 [  11263]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-09-27 12:13:23,116 [  15207]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2017-09-27 12:13:23,180 [  15271]   INFO - figurations.GeneralCommandLine - Cannot run program "D:\download\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\jre64\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\download\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\jre64\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.startProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:420)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:387)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.<init>(OSProcessHandler.java:45)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.CapturingProcessHandler.<init>(CapturingProcessHandler.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.util.ExecUtil.execAndGetOutput(ExecUtil.java:101)
    at com.intellij.util.JdkBundle.getJDKNameArchVersionAndUpdate(JdkBundle.java:230)
    at com.intellij.util.JdkBundle.createBundle(JdkBundle.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.JdkBundle.createBoot(JdkBundle.java:137)
    at com.intellij.util.JdkBundle.createBoot(JdkBundle.java:124)
    at com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor.checkRuntime(SystemHealthMonitor.java:101)
    at com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor.initComponent(SystemHealthMonitor.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:492)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:474)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:548)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:481)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:433)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:345)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 40 more
```

Thank you very much if you know what's going on. If this can't be resolved I might have to fail a course simply due to being unable to do the projects I need to do.

Comment: does this file exists? `D:\download\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\jre64\bin\java.exe`

Comment: Make sure your Maven plugin is enabled as well. In my case, it was disabled for an unknown reason. To enable it: Settings → Plugins → Installed (Scroll down to Bundled section)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have got the same problem with my IntelliJ Ultimate 17. The problem was that `JDK for importer` (maven in that case) was set to IntelliJ's internal.

1. Go to `Settings` (shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Then, `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> `Importing`
3. Choose other JDK than the internal one for `JDK for importer`.
4. Check if works, eventually - restart IntelliJ.

**Picture with settings:**

[image]

Comment: So I brought this menu up as you suggested but my Java home is not defined, at least according to IntelliJ. Do you guys know anything about that?

Comment: Just define it and try to add in the settings.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally got this blasted thing to work!